# After drush archive-restore of a backup tar in a new machine, how to configure apache2?

Tags: 7

I have a up and running Drupal 7 site in a Centos 6 machine and Drush 6.2.0 is being used. I need to migrate it to Ubuntu 22.04. I used drush archive-dump to create a backup tar. Then I moved it Ubuntu 22.04. I used drush archive-restore to restore the sites in the new machine. I successfully migrated public_html folder and mysql database.

As I understand from the installation guides, next step is to configure apache2 files to point public_html folder so that when I enter ip adress of my machine I can view my drupal sites. Unfortunately I failed to do that.

I tried https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-drupal-on-ubuntu-22-04/ instructions told in here even though this is for Drupal 9(I couldn't find any guide for Drupal 7 on ubuntu 22.04). I have a *drupal.conf* file in */etc/apache2/sites-available*.
Here is the inside of the drupal.conf :

```
<VirtualHost 193.140.196.110:80>
  ServerName tetam2.boun.edu.tr
  ServerAlias www.tetam2.boun.edu.tr
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html
  <Directory /var/www/html/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The folder */var/www/html/public_html* is my restored *public_html*.

I am not sure about what I did right and what I did wrong :(. After successfully running drush archive-restore command, I felt kinda lost. I would much appreciate any guidance in here.

Thanks for reading this far. Sorry if it is something very silly yet, I am incredibly lost here.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I read your question but I do not understand what in fact is not working here—you did not say. Configuring Apache on various platforms is a little out of scope for this forum but let us first understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: Thank you! My question here is after drush archive-restore command, what one should do to view drupal site? How can I test that I have successfully restored my backup from previous machine into the new machine?